# Formula to find the week no. (which week out of 52 weeks in year that date lies) from the date

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Is there a formula available to find the week number (which week out of 52 weeks in a year that date lies) from the date?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a date in A1,:

`=WEEKNUM(A1)`  will give the week number.....For example if A1 contains:

11/20/2013      the formula will return 47

Answer (score 3):

Try the Excel function `=WEEKNUM`

You can find more about the function [HERE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/weeknum-HP005209337.aspx)

In case the above link dies, here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: + 1 Amended your post so that in case the link dies then the future visitor doesn't have to look around :)

Comment: `I'll go back over some of your answers I have not already +1'd to 'compensate'!` Lol no you don't need to do that. Your post does answer OP's question. :)

Answer (score 3):

Excel's standard [WEEKNUM function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/weeknum-HP005209337.aspx) uses the US standard for week numbers (week containing Jan 1 == week 1).  If you need the [week number as defined in ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), you can check [this article](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/06/30/week-numbers-in-excel.aspx) which proposes the formula

```
=INT((B4-DATE(YEAR(B4-WEEKDAY(B4-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(B4-WEEKDAY(B4-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)
```

or, as a VBA function

```
Public Function IsoWeekNumber(d1 As Date) As Integer
' Attributed to Daniel Maher
    Dim d2 As Long
    d2 = DateSerial(Year(d1 - WeekDay(d1 - 1) + 4), 1, 3)
    IsoWeekNumber = Int((d1 - d2 + WeekDay(d2) + 5) / 7)
End Function
```

Note for those people using OpenOffice or LibreOffice Calc: the `WEEKNUM` function ([doc](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_WEEKNUM_function)) in these spreadsheet programs returns the ISO8601 week, the Excel compatible function is called `WEEKNUM_ADD` ([doc](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_WEEKNUM_ADD_function))

Comment: +1 for giving the ISO alternative

Comment: In Excel 2010 WEEKNUM's 2nd parameter can be set to **21** to get ISO week numbers (and in Excel 2013 there is an explicit ISOWEEKNUM function) - in earlier excel versions this formula will give you week number assuming date in A2 `=INT((A2-WEEKDAY(A2,2)-DATE(YEAR(A2+4-WEEKDAY(A2,2)),1,4))/7)+2`